# How do I correctly configure "www" for my website?

Tags: apache-2.2

How do I correctly configure "www" for my website?

I'm running a DNS test suite and receiving the following error message for www.wordswithfriends.net

Received: HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently (Server: Apache) Location: http://wordswithfriends.net/ 
Your main page redirects to another location. Several search engines will be unable to index your site.

This is not done in .htaccess at the moment as far as I can tell. How can I change it so that www.wordswithfriends.net does not redirect.  I have full admin rights. Currently I have both addresses pointing to the same IP.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are running WordPress, and you probably configured your site name to be just wordswithfriends.net. In order to use **www**.wordswithfriends.net, head into the Wordpress Admin pages and go to Settings => General. Prefix both "Wordpress Address" and "Site Address" with www., and your site should stop redirecting...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Apache is listen based on IP drop the Cname and setup another A record for www. pointing to the same IP as example.com.